# setSelection not working - getSelectedItemPosition always returns -1

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a Navigation Drawer. Everything is working fine except I can't change background of the item on selected state. The background is changed when pressed, but returns back to normal when released.

In my xml, I set both state_pressed and state_selected as color2, whereas normal is color1. I get color2 when pressed but back to color1 when released.

So, I checked my class to find where it went wrong, and saw that getSelectedItemPosition() always returns -1, though position returns correctly (explained below).

Any help please?

**EDIT 1:** Okay, I added getCheckedItemPosition() method as well, which returns correctly position correctly. But my listview background is not changed, though I used state_checked.

```
Log.d("postion",""+position);  // THIS RETURNS AS EXPECTED, LET SAY 2 FOR 3RD ITEM
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
Log.d("Selected",""+mDrawerList.getSelectedItemPosition()); // THIS ALWAYS RETURNS -1
Log.d("Checked",""+mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition()); // THIS RETURNS CORRECTLY, e.g. 2
```

LISTVIEW:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@color/col3"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_selector"
android:background="@color/col3"/>
```

MENU_SELECTOR:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_active" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_active" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_active" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_norm" />
</selector>
```

**LIST ITEM**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get position of an selected item from a ListView, even though there was no item selected. From the docs of `getSelectedItemPosition()`, you can see, that if no item is selected, then it returns the `INVALID_POSITION`, which is `-1`.

Comment: yaa, I know that .. point is, shouldn't it be selected by the previous line -- mDrawerList.setSelection(position); ?

Comment: also, any idea what I should add to have my selected item's background as "grad2" color?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_selector"
```

That is a drawable the ListView is to use for the currently selected item.  So, it get used after the ListView has determined the state of an item is the selected state.  So, you would set this to your `android:drawable="@color/grad2"`

```
android:listSelector="@color/grad2"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

Comment: I have updated the code in main question .. however, I tried using 
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true", but no positive result ...

Answer (score 0):

To make ListView highlight selections,you must ensure:

1. ListView is set to single or multiple choice mode.
2. The root View of each list item implements `Checkable`. You can use `CheckedTextView` for list items.
3. The background of list item view is set to a selector with different drawables for checked and normal states.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply ... 1) Choice mode is singleChoice ... 2) Not sure what do u mean. If you kindly elaborate .. 3) Already set (I updated the code)